# How to add values of a specific key in a map in a list in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting a list of maps via an api. Now i want to get the sum of all values of a specific key in the maps. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: You should mention what kind of data you are receiving. Have you converted it to Dart's `Map<X, Y>` form? Please provide some code.

Comment: Yes! i have decoded it from json.

Answer (score 0):

#### A simple for-loop should do the job

Since you have not provided any code, I am making a lot assumptions here, but I hope you get the idea.

```
List<Map<String, int>> mapList;
// Now add members to list

int sum = 0; // contains the sum of `field` values of all members
for(int i=0; i<mapList.length; i++) {
  sum += mapList[i]['field'];
}
```